# Use \IfEndWith with \ref and alnumsec.sty

Tags: hyperref, xstring

I'm using [alnumsec](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/alnumsec) for an alphanumeric section numbering.
I have a new command `\myreference` to create references with the `hyperref` package. This works fine.

I want all my footnotes created by `\myreference` to end with one dot. This is why I need to check if the section (for example: I.1.) already ends with a dot.
I tried to use `\IfEndWith{\detokenize{\ref{#1}}}{.}{(already has dot)}{.}` but it does not work.

---

This is my example:

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{alnumsec}
\alnumsectionlevels{1}{section,subsection,subsubsection}
\alnumsecstyle{Ral}

\newcommand{\myreference}[1]{
   \footnote{
    See page \pageref{#1}, section \ref{#1}
    \IfEndWith{\detokenize{\ref{#1}}}{.}{(already has dot)}{.}
   }
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}\label{a}
First section\myreference{a}
\subsection{jkhahjkas}
My subsection.
\subsubsection{three}\label{b}
Third section\myreference{b}

\end{document}
\endinput
```

Comment: The `\endinput` at the end after `\end{document}` has no effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\ref` isn't expandable, so `\IfEndWith` can not really work with `\ref`, but `\getrefnumber` from `refcount` package is expandable. The package is loaded by `hyperref` anyway.

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\usepackage{alnumsec}
\alnumsectionlevels{1}{section,subsection,subsubsection}
\alnumsecstyle{Ral}

\newcommand{\myreference}[1]{
   \footnote{
    See page \pageref{#1}, section \ref{#1}
    \IfEndWith{\getrefnumber{#1}}{.}{(already has dot)}{.}
   }
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}\label{a}
First section\myreference{a}
\subsection{jkhahjkas}
My subsection.
\subsubsection{three}\label{b}
Third section\myreference{b}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\@addpunct` from `amsthm` which will not add its argument if the current space factor is greater than 1000. However, this requires changing a bit the space factor after Roman numerals.

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{amsthm} % for \@addpunct
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{alnumsec}

\alnumsectionlevels{1}{section,subsection,subsubsection}
\alnumsecstyle{Ral}
\protected\def\Romanperiod{\spacefactor1001 .}
\surroundRoman{}{\Romanperiod}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myreference}[1]{% <-- don't forget
   \footnote{% <-- don't forget
     See page~\pageref{#1}, section~\ref{#1}\@addpunct{.}% <-- don't forget
   }% <-- don't forget
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section}\label{a}
First section\myreference{a}

\subsection{jkhahjkas}
My subsection.

\subsubsection{three}\label{b}
Third section\myreference{b}

\end{document}
```

Don't forget to mask end-of-lines in macro definitions.

[image]